# How to parse auth protected site in Java?

Tags: java, curl

I need to write a desktop application, probably on Java, or maybe there is some better tools(?) for parsing sites protected by authentication. 
Something like php-curl, but for java or another language.

Thanks.

Comment: What sort of authentication? Cookies, `.htaccess`, Sessions, ...?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748789/java-login-to-a-website-that-is-using-form-based-authentication) might be a starting point for further research...

Comment: Sorry, my question is what lib i need to use, or maybe better try another language?

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools like this. One of them is HTMLUnit, it's a tool for unit testing web applications but it can also be used for parsing sites. Another one is Selenium which was created with the same purpose.